# Uploading a file in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to upload a file using PHP.

My folder structure is the following:

I have a directory called `schemas` in my root htdocs folder. Inside this folder, I want to create a new folder for every user; in this folder I'll be storing user-specific files.

For now, my code is incomplete (doesn't check whether or not the folder/file already exists and might error on this), but I'm just trying to get the basics to work.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES ["bestand"] ["error"] > 0) {
//for error messages: see http://php.net/manual/en/features.fileupload.errors.php
switch ($_FILES ["bestand"] ["error"]) {
case 1 :
$msg = "U mag maximaal 2MB opladen.";
break;
default :
$msg = "Sorry, uw upload kon niet worden verwerkt.";
}
} else {
//check MIME TYPE - http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php
$allowedtypes = array ("application/pdf" );
$filename = $_FILES ["bestand"] ["tmp_name"];
$finfo = new finfo ( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
$fileinfo = $finfo->file ( $filename );

if (in_array ( $fileinfo, $allowedtypes )) {
//move uploaded file
$dir = "schemas";
chdir("schemas");
$user_folder = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['schema']);
mkdir( $user_folder, 0777);
//  echo getcwd();
//  closedir($open);
$folder = "/schemas/" . $user_folder . "/" . $_FILES ["bestand"] ["name"];
echo $folder;
echo $user_folder;

if (move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ["bestand"] ["tmp_name"], $folder )) {
$msg = "Uw schema is succesvol geupload!";
} else {
$msg = "Upload mislukt.";
}
} else {
$msg = "U kan enkel een pdf uploaden.";
}
}
echo $msg . "<br />"; 

?>
```

When I try this, I get the following warnings:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/schemas/loesp/loopschema-0-tot-5-kilometer.pdf) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sportjefit2/uploadenfile.php on line 30

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpMsxxsu' to '/schemas/loesp/loopschema-0-tot-5-kilometer.pdf' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sportjefit2/uploadenfile.php on line 30
```

The script **does** create the folder (in this case `loesp`) but does not seem to upload or move the actual file. I'm stumped.

Comment: *(reference)* http://de2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Try using full paths instead of relative ones, see if that helps. Additionally, from reviewing the manual it seems like destinatin should contain the destination file name aswell, and not just the folder name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an absolute path, which starts in the root of the entire machine. You should use a relative path, and it should start from the current working directory.

You already are inside the `schemas` folder (after the call to chdir), so $folder should be set to this:

```
$folder = $user_folder . "/" . $_FILES ["bestand"] ["name"];
```